# Why catchError is not able to catch the error?

Tags: dart

Minimal reproducible code:

```dart
Future<void> foo() async => throw Future.error('Foo');

void main() {
  foo().catchError(print);
}
```

I'm still seeing this error on the console

> Dart Unhandled Exception: Foo, stack trace:

If I throw `FlutterError(...)`, the error is caught but `Future.error(...)` fails. The reason is that the error coming out is itself a `Future`, but how can I handle that?

Comment: Use return instead of throw?

Comment: @julemand101 I know that will work but why `throw` isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

### Async marked methods are running sync until first await

Your `async` marked method is in fact not really running as another event on the event queue until the first `await` is happening.

In this case, it means the exception is actually thrown before we have time to assign any error handling and we are therefore getting an error for that. This behavior can be found in the documentation of `catchError`:

> Note that futures don't delay reporting of errors until listeners are added. If the first catchError (or then) call happens after this future has completed with an error then the error is reported as unhandled error.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-async/Future/catchError.html

The fix for this is to actually make an `await` before throwing the exception so lets do that:

```
Future<void> foo() async {
  await Future<void>.value();
  throw Future.error('Foo');
}

void main() {
  foo().catchError(print);
}
```

But we are now getting the following error as output which we need to look into:

```
Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
Unhandled exception:
Foo
```

### Throw inside async block converts object to Future error

The `Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'` is a line which comes from the `print` method which are trying to print the error. As we can see, we are somewhat getting a `Future` object here. This object is actually the object created from `Future.error('Foo')`.

In Dart we are allowed to `throw` whatever object we want. In `async` marked method, this object is going to be packed inside a `Future.error`. So in your case, what you actually have done is `Future.error(Future.error('Foo'))`.

You are then handling the outer error but not the inner one. If we do this instead:

```
Future<void> foo() async {
  await Future<void>.value();
  throw Future.error('Foo');
}

Future<void> main() async {
  await foo().catchError((Object obj) => (obj as Future).catchError(print));
}
```

This will return:

```
Foo
```

Since we are now calling `catchError` on the `Future` created by `Future.error('Foo')`.

Comment: Did you read my next section? My whole point is there are two problems in your code and we need to fix both of them before we can actually catch the error. :)

Comment: Quoting your `Your async marked method is in fact not really running as another event on the event queue until the first await is happening`, but why code like this works `Future<int> f() async => 1`

Comment: @iDecode Because a `Future` is allowed to have a `sync` value. Try add some `print` statements around your code and you will see in what order the code are executed. The `async` tag will make sure your `1` is packed inside a `Future` like `Future.value(1)`.

Comment: Alright, thanks. A little side question though, how do you know all these things, they are not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @iDecode Followed the development of the Dart language since my thesis about the language (with some distributed computing extension for the language) at the university 7 years ago. I find it interesting to read language specifications and follow language and SDK issues on the Dart github project. Also find it interesting to digging into specific stuff in the changelog to see how tings works and implemented inside e.g. the Dart VM.

Comment: And it is not that stuff is not written down. In this case, the nature of code (in async block) running sync until `await` is written in the documentation: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#execution-flow-with-async-and-await

Comment: Thanks for sharing the secret with me. You indeed deserve to be in the top Dart expert list.

Comment: @iDecode Thanks. Should properly add that Dart is really just a hobby for me and not really used at my workplace (only really small areas where I made some internal scripting). At work, it is mostly Java applications I am working on. Not that it has less problems which needs to be analyzed... But there are already a lot of Java experts on StackOverflow so I have just chosen to dedicate my spare time to the Dart tag. :)

Comment: Ahhh that's strange. So, your main language is Java (and Dart is only the hobby), now I can't imagine how amazing you're in Java already.

Comment: @iDecode Properly not that amazing outside our own project since we are a little stuck with Java 8 (Java 11 are on the way but there are lot of third party libraries and source code there needs to be fixed...). :D

Comment: I also started my journey with Java (till 8, haha) and then I found out Dart which is way more easier and really a fun language to learn. I have learnt a lot from you (you've answered many questions of mine :)

Comment: You also wrote the same answer 2-3 seconds after Danny posted the answer. You keep al the references at your finger tip.

Comment: @AndresSilva Please don't ask people to help with your question in comments on other questions. I am helping people when I have the time and I can see that I am able to answer the question. In your case, I ignored your question because I don't have the needed skills to help you (I don't do any Flutter development at all and I don't know that much about Flutter). But I need to say that it is really annoying to get comments from people about questions I have already chosen to ignore. I don't need anybody to tell me what questions I should take a look at. I am fully capable to do that myself. :)