# Difference between throwing and returning a Future.error

Tags: dart

**Minimal reproducible code**

```dart
Future<void> foo() async {
  final fooError = Future.error('FooError');
  return Future.error(fooError);
}

Future<void> bar() async {
  await Future(() {});
  throw Future.error('BarError');
}

void main() {
  foo().catchError((e) => (e as Future).catchError(print)); // Error is NOT handled. 
  bar().catchError((e) => (e as Future).catchError(print)); // Error is handled. 
}
```

As you can see, `BarError` is handled but not the `FooError`. AFAIK, when you mark a method `async` and use `throw`, the error is wrapped in a `Future.error(...)`. But my first code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Future.error()` creates a `Future` that completes with an error during a future microtask. This means that if the created `Future` doesn't have a listener when the microtask is executed, it's considered unhandled and will cause the program to terminate. I'm not 100% sure what's triggering the microtask to be executed, but the microtask queue is always executed and drained until it's empty before executing the next event in the isolate's event loop.

However, those details aren't terribly important. To fix this issue, update your example to not wrap your `Future.error('FooError')` with another `Future.error(...)`, things work as expected:

```dart
Future<void> foo() async {
  return Future.error('FooError');
}

Future<void> bar() async {
  await Future(() {});
  throw 'BarError';
}

void main() {
  foo().catchError(print); // Error is now handled.
  bar().catchError(print); // Error is handled. 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1). However, `bar().catchError(print);` won't really catch the exception unless you do what I wrote in the post. I already knew the solution, [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66952684/12483095) (removing one `Future.error`). All I wanted to know was what `return` and `throw` are doing with `Future.error`, why they are behaving differently.

Comment: Ah I missed that (and didn't run the code I posted with the `bar().catchError(print)`... :-) I've updated it to work correctly now).

Comment: To answer your question, `return Future.error()` and `throw 'Some exception'` will do the same thing, assuming your function is marked `async`. The `throw` syntax in an asynchronous function is just basically syntactic sugar for directly returning `Future.error()`. However, using `throw` in a non-async function that returns a `Future` won't result in an error `Future` being returned, but a synchronous exception being thrown.

Comment: In `bar` you don't need `await Future` anymore if you had removed `Future.error` from it. Again things are so messed up (in my head for `Future.error` part). I totally understand what you mentioned about making a function `async` and throwing something from it is essentially a `Future.error`, but then is `throw Future.error())` isn't equivalent to `return Future.error(Future.error))`?

Comment: The microtask queue is executed before you can install the error handler for your nested `Future.error` which causes it to be completed and considered an unhandled exception. Both `Future.error` instances will complete at the same time (sometime before the `foo().catchError((e) => e as Future)` is executed), so you'll never be able to properly return a nested `Future.error` while still being able to handle the nested error.

Comment: I didn't read your full comment yet, and accepting the answer. Tomorrow, I'll get back to this. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: Not a problem! Always glad to help :-)

Comment: I understood most part of your comment. Does `Future.error` alone executes in the microtask queue and not in the event queue?

Comment: The completion of the `Future.error` is a result of a microtask being completed. This is so developers have the period of time before the next asynchronous suspension (at which point the microtask queue is drained) to install error handlers. This also ensures that the `Future.error` is fully completed before the next event is handled.