# Why can't catch exceptions with "catchError" in Dart?

Tags: dart, future

Test:

```
void testAs() async {
  try {
    String b = await test();
    print(b);
  } catch (e) {
    print("1 await error");
  }
  test().then((value) => print(value)).catchError(() {
    print("2 then  error");
  });
}

Future<String> test() {
  List<String> bb = ["2222"];
  return Future.value(bb[1]);
}





 1 await error
 RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1
```

Why is it ineffective?
If I want to deal with "future" through "then", how should I catch the exception and not let it throw out.

Comment: Because its caught by catch statement in this case. You need to refractor your solution

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/66952192/.  The error is thrown *synchronously* when `test()` is invoked, before `.catchError` is even called.  Just use `async`/`await` and let it do all the work for you when you use `try`/`catch`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you friends,the last problem has been solved,the problem can be solved by adding `async` and `await` flags to the `test()`  method.

But there is a new problem, Now I use the correct code and find that it can only be printed once.why can't it print "then success",then the program ends
,modify as follows:

```
void testAs() async {
  try {
    await test();
    print("await success");
  } catch (e) {
    print("await error");
  }

  test().then((value) => print("then success")).catchError((e) {
    print("then  error");

  });
}

Future<String> test() async{
  List<String> bb = ["2222"];
 
  return await Future.value(bb[0]);

}
```

print:await success

Comment: Just make the `test` function's return statement be `return bb[0];`. It's the same thing, just more efficient.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but now I don’t understand why "then success" is not printed out? Only one of them can be printed between them. I want to print both "success"?

Comment: If you *await* the future created by `test().then(....)...`, then your `testAs` function won't return before printing "then success". I'm guessing that's what happens.

Comment: I understand,Thank you~