# Can't handle errors when calling a Firebase Callable Function from Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am calling a Firebase Callable Function from Flutter and, although I have tried pretty much everything, I am still unable to handle errors thrown by the callable function.

My Callable Function looks like this:

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

export const myFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    //Get data passed to the function
    const someData = data.someData;
    
    //Run transaction
    return db.runTransaction(async (transaction: any) => {
        //Get data
        const docRef = db.collection("myCollection").doc("myDocId");
        const docResults = await transaction.get(docRef);
        const docData = docResults.data();

        //Run validations:
        if(1 != 0){
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', "Error on purpose");
        }
        
        //Create a new doc
        const newDocRef = db.collection('myCollection').doc();
        transaction.set(newDocRef, {someData: "myData",});

        return {newDocId: newDocRef.id}
    });

  });
```

I then created a `Future` in Flutter to call my callable function:

```dart
import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';

Future<String> callMyFunction({String someData,}) async {
  HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable(
      'myFunction',  options: HttpsCallableOptions(timeout: Duration(seconds: 5)));

  try {
    return callable.call({
      'someData': someData,
    }).then((results) {
      return results.data['newDocId'].toString();
    }).catchError(handleError); //First error handler
  } catch (error) {
    //Second error handler
    print("Missed the first error handler.");
    handleError(error);
    return null;
  }
}

void handleError(error) {
  print("Got this error:");
  print(error);
}
```

Finally, I call my future from a `TextButton` with yet another Error Handler:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myApp/callableFuture.dart';

class myWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      child: Text("Press me"),
      onPressed: () {
        callMyFunction(
          someData: "Hi",
        ).catchError((error) {
          //This is my third error handler
          print("Missed first two error handlers. Got this error:");
          print(error);
        }).then((newDocId) =>
            print("Got this doc id: $newDocId"));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

When I call my function and get an error, my code immidiately jumps to -and is stopped at- Flutter's `method_channel_https_callable.dart` (which is located at `.../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_functions_platfrom_interface-5..0.15/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart`).

It stops at the class `MethodChannelHttpsCallable` at the function `call`, right here:

```dart
try {
      //...some code...

      if (result is Map) {
        return Map<String, dynamic>.from(result);
      } else {
        return result;
      }
    } catch (e, s) {
      throw convertPlatformException(e, s); //My code stops right here.
    }
```

Finally, once I click on `Step Over` (in VSCode) the following is printed to the console:

> Got this error:
>
> [firebase_functions/failed-precondition] Error on purpose.
>
> #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
> package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:597
>
> #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
> package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:158
>
> <asynchronous suspension>
>
> #2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call
> package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:23
>
> <asynchronous suspension>
>
> #3      HttpsCallable.call
> package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:35
>
> Got this doc id: null

Comment: So, apparently there are two parts to this. 1) The code was printing all of the error above because of this line in my `handleError` function: `print(error);`. I solved that part by changing it to: `print(error.code); print(error.message);`.

Comment: Part 2) The code still halts as an unhandled error. After reading through the documentation I stumbled upon this line at `catchError`: *"Note that futures don't delay reporting of errors until listeners are added. If the first catchError (or then) call happens after this future has completed with an error then the error is reported as unhandled error."*. It led me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66952192/why-catcherror-is-not-able-to-catch-the-error). I don't fully understand the solution so I haven't been able to fix my code yet. But I think it might be on the right track.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why, but this solved the issue:

I changed my future that calls the callable function from this:

```dart
import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';

Future<String> callMyFunction({String someData,}) async {
  HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable(
      'myFunction',  options: HttpsCallableOptions(timeout: Duration(seconds: 5)));

  try {
    return callable.call({
      'someData': someData,
    }).then((results) {
      return results.data['newDocId'].toString();
    }).catchError(handleError); //First error handler
  } catch (error) {
    //Second error handler
    print("Missed the first error handler.");
    handleError(error);
    return null;
  }
}

void handleError(error) {
  print("Got this error:");
  print(error);
}
```

to this:

```
import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';

Future<String> callMyFunction({String someData,}) async {
  HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable(
      'myFunction',  options: HttpsCallableOptions(timeout: Duration(seconds: 5)));

  HttpsCallableResult results;

  try {
    results = await callable.call({
      'someData': someData,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    print("Got this error:");
    print(error.code);
    print(error.message);
    return null;
  }

  return results.data['newDocId'].toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your output logs and code, it is clear that your first error handler is resolving or handling the error for you, based on this line:

```dart
I/flutter (21112): Got this error: I/flutter (21112): [firebase_functions/failed-precondition] Error on purpose.
```

Since the error coming from the Firebase function is handled (or “resolved”) by the first error handler, the other two error handlers have no reason to run, since they are receiving no errors. This makes the Future executed from your button to be resolved, albeit with a `null` value.

What you can do in this scenario is to `rethrow` the error within your first error handler as [recommended to do](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use-rethrow-to-rethrow-a-caught-exception) in Dart, so it can be dealt with in the second handler, and rethrow it once more to the third handler. I believe in this scenario the second handler is redundant, and you could rethrow the error from the first handler to the third handler. `catchError()` clauses [already work](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling#examples-of-using-then-with-catcherror) as try/catch blocks in Dart.

**Firebase Function**

```js
exports.myFuncEmu = functions.https.onCall((data,context) => {
  const testData = data.text;

  if(testData == "throwEx"){
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', "Error on purpose");
  }

  console.log(testData);
  return `Finished: ${testData}`
});
```

**Flutter Future**

```dart
Future<String?> runFunction(String text) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseFunctions.instance.useFunctionsEmulator('localhost', 5001);
  HttpsCallable callableFunc =
      FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable("myFuncEmu");

  try {
    return await callableFunc.call(
      {"text": text},
    ).then((res) {
      return res.data.toString();
    }).catchError(handleError); //Handler from callable function
  } catch (err) {
    print("Missed the first error handler"); //Try/catch block handler
    rethrow; //Throws here so it can be caught by Future handler in button widget
    return null;
  }
}

String handleError(err) {
  print("Caught error: ");
  print(err);
  throw Exception(err); //Throws here so it can be caught by try/catch handler
  return "";
}
```

**Flutter button**

```dart
child: ElevatedButton( //Swapped order of then and catcherror clauses
                onPressed: () {
                  runFunction("throwEx")
                      .then((val) => print("Final result: ${val}"))
                      .catchError((err) {
                    print(
                        "Missed first two error handlers"); //Handler from Future function
                    print(err);
                  });
                },
                child: const Text(
                  "RUN",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
```

Adding the needed throw/rethrow statements, we can redirect this error properly through error handlers, so that code can be blocked from executing after an error is found:

```
Caught error:
[firebase_functions/failed-precondition] Error on purpose
Missed the first error handler
Missed first two error handlers
Exception: [firebase_functions/failed-precondition] Error on purpose
```

Omitting rethrow/throw statements:

```
Caught error:
[firebase_functions/failed-precondition] Error on purpose
Final result: //Incorrectly continues code, seems to not be handling errors
```

Comment: @AndresSilva were you able to resolve this issue? in case other users have similar problems.

Comment: Thanks. So, I thought so too, but what's troubling me is the fact that the code stops and prints all of the above as if the error isn't being handled correctly. In other ocassions when I use a 'catchError' in Flutter the code just keeps running. It seems like something is not entirely right here.

Comment: @AndresSilva I simplified your code a bit to test this out, and as far as I can see, it does indeed work similarly to what I explained. I edited my answer to show the full code and the results I obtained after running the code as-is and after adding the needed error rethrow statements to redirect this error as needed. **The `catchError()` clause in the button widget was not properly catching errors until I placed it after the `then()` clause**.

Comment: Thanks. Please check my two comments to my original post above.