# Future.catchError doesn't catch error thrown by camera plugin's CameraController.initialize

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-future

I'm trying to understand why my code doesn't work. I'm using the Flutter camera plugin, and want to handle cases when camera permissions are denied. In such cases `CameraController.initialize` should throw an exception.

I was trying this out:

```
CameraController _controller;
//...
await _controller.initialize().catchError((err) {
   print(err);
   // other stuff
});
```

If rejecting camera access while running the app, the exception is thrown as expected, but `catchError` doesn't catch it, and the app crashes.

So I tried this:

```
Future<void> doStuff() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000)); //also tried with Duration.zero
  throw Exception("error");
}
//...
await doStuff().catchError((err) {
  print(err);
  // other stuff
})
```

In this case, `catchError` catches the exception. Why is this happening? What's the difference between `_controller.initialize()` and `doStuff()`?
I can overcome this by using try / catch instead of `catchError`, but I'm interested to find out what's going on in my code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66952192/why-catcherror-is-not-able-to-catch-the-error does this answer your question?

Comment: Not really. Even if I throw the exception in doStuff() without any delay, the error is still caught by catchError.